# Подтверждение игры node-dota2

Tags: node.js

[image: Проблема]
Требуется подтвердить готовность к игре с помощью GameCoordinator.

Структура данного "пакета" в Protobuf

```
message CMsgReadyUp {
    optional .DOTALobbyReadyState state = 1 [default = DOTALobbyReadyState_UNDECLARED];
    optional fixed64 ready_up_key = 2;
    optional .CDOTAClientHardwareSpecs hardware_specs = 3;
}
```

```
enum DOTALobbyReadyState {
    DOTALobbyReadyState_UNDECLARED = 0;
    DOTALobbyReadyState_ACCEPTED = 1;
    DOTALobbyReadyState_DECLINED = 2;
}
```

На днях всё работало идеально. Сегодня проверяю - реакции ноль.

Код:

```js
let readyUpKey = utils.calculateReadyUpKey(client.lobby.id, client.dota.AccountID).toString();

let payload = {
    state: dota2.schema.lookupEnum('DOTALobbyReadyState').values.DOTALobbyReadyState_ACCEPTED,
    ready_up_key: readyUpKey
};

let encodedPayload = dota2.schema.lookupType('CMsgReadyUp').encode(payload).finish();

client.dota.sendToGC(dota2.schema.lookupEnum('EDOTAGCMsg').values.k_EMsgGCReadyUp, encodedPayload, (message, callback) => {
    console.log('#1', message, callback);
}, (err, resp) => {
    console.log('#2', err, resp);
});
```

`client.dota` = `Dota2.Dota2Client`

`calculateReadyUpKey`:

```js
this.calculateReadyUpKey = (lobby, steamid) => {
    let lobbyId = this.calculateSteamID64(lobby);

    let userIdShifted = bigInt(steamid).shiftLeft(32);

    let userIdRes = bigInt(steamid).or(userIdShifted).not();

    let res = bigInt(lobbyId).xor(userIdRes);

    return res;
};
```

(Человеческий вид)

```java
lobbyId ^ ~(userId | (userId << 32))
```

Возможно это из-за обновления доты, но никакой информации об этом не нашёл. Protobuf обновлял.

Comment: И никаких ошибок?